# How can we access cookies created by APEX Cookie Class in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can we access cookies created by APEX Cookie Class in Javascript
I have created a cookie in APEX code, but now i want access that Cookie in salesforce, how can i achieve that, or guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APEX Cookie Class Create Cookies in the form of 
apex__`Name of Cookie in APEX Code`, [Ex: apex__username ]

so if you name cookie as 'username'  in apex
it will be 'apex__username' in javascript